# Import Custom .NET Library into Blue Prism Automate Folder

Tags: c#, .net, blueprism, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I am trying to create a custom library in C# using Visual Studio and then be able to refer to it from code-stages in BP objects. I know that the .dll has to be placed in the Automate folder for BP to see it, but what about .exe, config and all other files? Just placing the .dll only in the Automate folder doesn't seem to work for me. I did reference it under Code Options on the Initialize page and also placed a Namespace under Namespace Imports. But BP still tells me that the library is missing. Do I need to package as NuGet or some other way? I have zero experience doing this, so I am sorry if this is basic.
I was wondering if someone could point out some tutorial or information on how to do this A-Z, or maybe share their experience doing this? Thank you.

Comment: *"I know that the .dll has to be placed in the Automate folder for BP to see it"* Where did you read this? I've been able to reference absolute paths to DLLs before just fine.

Comment: Ok. Any idea why this is not working then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a DLL to be used with Blue Prism, the best thing to do is to compile the code with all its references and resources into a single DLL.

I have always used [Costura Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) to achieve that for usage in BP several times.